# Woocommerce custom category page with pagination

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic

I want to create woocommerce category custom template. i am not sure i am doing it the correct way or not. What i did  is I edited `taxonomy-product_cat.php` file. ,

In my code i am able to get category thumbnail image, category description, 5 products.  but now issue is no matter what category i am browsing i  always see same category products. Does that mean category query is not correct. Also i want to  add pagination also. **< Previous 1,2,3.. Next >**

Below is the code

```
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying products in a product category. Simply includes the archive template.
 *
 * Override this template by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/taxonomy-product_cat.php
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     1.6.4
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}
get_header( 'shop' ); ?>
<?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_before_main_content hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
         * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );
    ?>
<div class="category-header">

 <div class="cat-thumb">  <?php

   // verify that this is a product category page
if (is_product_category()){
    global $wp_query;
    // get the query object
    $cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
    // get the thumbnail id user the term_id
    $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true ); 
    // get the image URL
    $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id ); 
    // print the IMG HTML
    echo '<img src="'.$image.'" alt="" />';
}

   ?></div>


<?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>

<h1 class="page-title">  <?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_archive_description hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_product_archive_description - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' );
        ?>
        </div>
<ul class="cat-products">
  <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'paged' => $paged,
            'posts_per_page' => 5
            );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();



                ?>
  <li <?php post_class( $classes ); ?>>
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' ); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
   <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );

            /**
             * woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_title - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' );

            /**
             * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_rating - 5
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_price - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
        ?>

          <p>&nbsp;</p>

     <div class="product-desp">  <?php
echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 27, '...' );
?></div>
    </a>

    <?php

        /**
         * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );

    ?>
  </li>
  <?php
            endwhile;
        } else {
            echo __( 'No products found' );
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
</ul>

<?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_after_main_content hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content)
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );
    ?>
<?php get_footer( 'shop' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the taxonomy query. You can read more about it on codex.
I have edited your code a bit. For pagination i have used next, previous navigation.

Give this code try it should work

```
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying products in a product category. Simply includes the archive template.
 *
 * Override this template by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/taxonomy-product_cat.php
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     1.6.4
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}
get_header( 'shop' ); ?>
<?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_before_main_content hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
         * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );
    ?>
<div class="category-header">

 <div class="cat-thumb">  <?php

   // verify that this is a product category page
if (is_product_category()){
    global $wp_query;
    // get the query object
    $cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
    // get the thumbnail id user the term_id
    $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true ); 
    // get the image URL
    $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id ); 
    // print the IMG HTML
    echo '<img src="'.$image.'" alt="" />';
}

   ?></div>


<?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>

<h1 class="page-title">  <?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_archive_description hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_product_archive_description - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' );
        ?>
        </div>
<ul class="cat-products">
  <?php 
        $paged= (get_query_var('paged' )) ? get_query_var('paged'):1;
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'paged' => $paged,
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'tax_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                                'field'    => 'id',
                                'terms'    => $cat->term_id,
                            ),
                        ),
            );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();



                ?>
  <li <?php post_class( $classes ); ?>>
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' ); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
   <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );

            /**
             * woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_title - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' );

            /**
             * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_rating - 5
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_price - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
        ?>

          <p>&nbsp;</p>

     <div class="product-desp">  <?php
echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 27, '...' );
?></div>
    </a>

    <?php

        /**
         * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );

    ?>
  </li>
  <?php
            endwhile;
        } else {
            echo __( 'No products found' );
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
</ul>
<div class="pagination">
            <p class="pull-left previous" ><?php previous_posts_link( '&larr; Previous ', $loop->max_num_pages  ); ?></p>
            <p class="pull-right next" ><?php next_posts_link( 'More  &rarr;', $loop->max_num_pages  ); ?></p>
          </div>

<?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_after_main_content hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content)
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );
    ?>
<?php get_footer( 'shop' ); ?>
```

Comment: thank you so much. i checked pagination not work properly . when i cilck More  then it is redirect me home page. and permalink link show ...../fashion/page/2/

but one issue solve before category content not coming properly now. now it is coming properly